# How to make a v-textarea fill the screen vertically?

Tags: css

I'm using Vuetify and I want a page that is mostly one big v-textarea.  There is some stuff on top, and maybe on the bottom, but besides that I want the page filled with v-textarea, with no scrolling (except scrolling inside the v-textarea).  I feel adding a style like "height:calc(100vh - 100px)" is a bit hack.

Is there some way I can do this the real way?

Thanks.

Comment: There's a `height` prop that you could set to `calc(100vh-100px)`. It's an official component prop and technically not directly setting a style, so perhaps not as hacky as you might think.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you call "the real way", but in one (more or less real) way or another you have to tell the `<textarea>` or one of its ancestors to fill up the free space of your viewport.

The typical solution is to have a parent wrapper which fills up the viewport, with `display: flex; flex-direction: column` and give your element `flex-grow: 1`

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0; }
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
  
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.wrapper > * {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
.wrapper > textarea {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    Some variable height stuff...
    <hr>
    <div contenteditable="true">Click to edit and make this element taller.<br> The textarea will adjust accordingly.</div>
  </div>
  <textarea>Your text area...</textarea>
</div>
```

The advantage is you don't have to hardcode the difference into `<textarea>`'s height. Instead, you tell it: fill up the available free space.